# OnChanged() Method triggered more than twice

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-jetpack, mutablelivedata

I am integrating insta API when I received auth token onTokenReceived() Called.

when I open the app then First time it works fine but when I came back to same activity again after pressing the back button then after they onChanged() method inside onTokenReceived called more than twice.
I have no idea how to resolve this. Please help me to solve this.

**EditProfileActivity.class**

```
 //instantiationg viewmodel
editProfileViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(EditProfileViewModel.class);



@Override
    public void onTokenReceived(String auth_code) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onTokenReceived: " + auth_code);

        editProfileViewModel.authInit(auth_code);
        editProfileViewModel.observe().observe(this, authToken -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: " + authToken.getAccessToken());
            INSTA_TOKEN = authToken.getAccessToken();
            Intent intent = new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this,FbAlbumsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("flag" , true);
            intent.putExtra("AuthTokenClass",authToken);
            startActivityForResult(intent,INSTA_IMAGE_PIC);
        });
    }
```

**EditProfileViewModel.class**

```
public class EditProfileViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = "EditProfileViewModel";

    private EditProfileRepo mRepo;

    private MutableLiveData<AuthToken>data = null;

    public void authInit(String code){
        if(data != null)
            return;
        mRepo = EditProfileRepo.getInstance();
        data = mRepo.getAccessToken(code);
    }

    public LiveData<AuthToken> observe(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

**EditProfileRepo.class**

public class EditProfileRepo {

```
private static final String TAG = "EditProfileRepo";
private static EditProfileRepo instance = null;
public MutableLiveData<AuthToken>data = new MutableLiveData<>();

public static EditProfileRepo getInstance(){
    if(instance == null)
        instance = new EditProfileRepo();

    return instance;
}

public MutableLiveData<AuthToken> getAccessToken(String code){
    Auth auth = AuthClient.getInstance();

    Call<AuthToken> authTokenCall = auth.getAuthToken(Constants.CLIENTID, Constants.CLIENTSECRET, "authorization_code", Constants.REDIRECTURI,
            code);


    authTokenCall.enqueue(new Callback<AuthToken>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AuthToken> call, Response<AuthToken> response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response.body().getAccessToken());
            data.setValue(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AuthToken> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });

    return data;
}
```

}

Comment: It happens because observers are bound to lifecycles. When you start another activity current activity stops so the observer isn't live anymore, after you return to the activity the observer is started again so the last available data is given to it. Try `SingleEventLiveData` pattern which is mentioned. There are different good implementations of it you can find.

Comment: You shouldn't register a new observer each time you get a new token

Answer (score 1):

LiveData act in this way. If you want another behaviour you should recearch internet with key words `SingleEventLiveData`